# Excel "if-then" and VLOOKUP formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Revenue:

[image: Revenue]

Company Info:

[image: Company info]

From the 'revenue' sheet I want the values from the revenue column to go into the sheet 'company info,' column C.

To do that, I want it to first check that each company name from 'revenue' sheet is in the associated column in the 'company info' sheet and then check to see if each Company Id from the 'revenue' sheet is in the company ID column in the 'company info sheet'.  If both of those are correct, then return the associated revenue in the company info sheet, column C.

Comment: If you can add another column (next) to your source, you can solve this by concatenating the fields (`=concatenate(a1,b2)` or just `=a1&b1`) and doing a `VLOOKUP` or an `INDEX` & `MATCH` to that one column.

Comment: I updated the images, any better?

Comment: I updated the images  and my description above to better explain , I hope this helps.

Comment: You made a simple example and have some labeled data.  So far, so good.  In creating the example there's some confusion that either is inadvertent or is a complexity not described.  Company ID 1 is Macys on Revenue and Jane on Co Info.  Should Co Name and ID always have the same association between lists?  If the data in the sequence given doesn't match, do you ignore it?  Or, are the companies not necessarily in the same order (or even not identical lists), so you need to find the company's entry on the other sheet to retrieve the data?  What to do if the data isn't found or doesn't match?

Comment: yes so company ID and company name are dependent on each other meaning, jane is associated with ID 1 and ID 1 is associated with  company Jane and etc. If there is no match return blank.

Comment: It still isn't clear whether you're just performing a validation check on lists that should match and be in the same sequence, or the lists are not in the same sequence and you need to search for matching records.  The solutions are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is with structured references, because Excel Table objects make life easier. I called the first screenshot table "Source" and the second screenshot table "Target". Replace with A1 ranges if you need to

[image]

Formula in cell C2 of the Company Info sheet is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Source[Revenue],
MATCH([@[Company Name]]&[@[Company ID]],
INDEX(Source[Company Name]&Source[Company ID],0),0)),"")
```

Don't use with whole columns unless you enjoy staring at the "calculating 2% ..." message. With Excel Tables, the column ranges are defined to only the table rows. If you don't want to use tables, consider dynamic range names instead. Anything but whole columns.